# Why do all objects bend upon joining them?

Tags: modeling, shortcut

I made some meshes for a game I make in UE4 (two bended cubes that form a bended cross, and a ico sphere that has the cross on it). When I joined two cubes everything was displayed as I want it to be.

I then proceeded to copy that 3 times and put the crosses around the ico spehere, but when I now select all crosses and the ico sphere and join them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> the Ico sphere and the crosses bend to the top left corner of the screen.

Can someone tell me how to join objects without deforming them?

EDIT: I applied all the *Simple Deform* modifiers

Answer (score 1):

When you join objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, only the modifiers of the Active object are kept. (Active = the last one you selected, appears in lighter orange).

What you can do is Apply all the modifiers before joining. Just click Apply under the name of the modifier, for each object.

Comment: I allready applied all the modifiers when I wrote this question, should have said it sorry. EDIT: But when the sphere is the last selected object it doesn't bend. I really don't get why it works this way when the modifier was applied after making the first bar of the cross